# No such file or directory: /etc/ssl/certs/example-cert.pem

Tags: php, drupal, amazon-web-services, nginx, ubuntu-13.10

I'm using [Drupal wit Nginx](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx). Rroot is `/var/www/example.com`, and I'm using PHP-FPM method.

After running through pretty typical troubleshooting, I ran into an error that I can only find one other instance of via google search:

```
BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/certs/example-cert.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:
fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/example-cert.pem','r')
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

I've tried commenting out HTTPS server in my sites-available config file, but continue to get the error. This is on a fresh instance of Ubuntu 13.10 on AWS.

Comment: did you run `sudo service nginx reload/restart` after commenting the lines?

Comment: Yes.  I'm not an nginx expert, but have enough experience to have done the basics (e.g. reload, sudo nginx to troubleshoot issues, installed everything I need to get rolling with my web server + Drupal).

Comment: Commented out request for certs and the additional calls to 80 and 443 and the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

create ls -s file -> enlace

```
    armonia.insertmendoza.com.ar.chain.pem -> ./armonia.insertmendoza.com.ar/chain.pem
    armonia.insertmendoza.com.ar.crt -> ./armonia.insertmendoza.com.ar/fullchain.pem
    armonia.insertmendoza.com.ar.dhparam.pem -> ./dhparam.pem
    armonia.insertmendoza.com.ar.key -> ./armonia.insertmendoza.com.ar/key.pem
```

It's woking!